# Tag colors not changing by changing the color scheme to Dreamweaver in Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, sublimetext3

I have downloaded the dreamweaver color scheme from this link:-

```
https://github.com/mghweb/SublimeDreamweaver
```

and after that i did this

```
1. Change your Color Scheme to "Dreamweaver" (at: Preferences > Color Scheme > Dreamweaver > Dreamweaver)
```

The second point i didn't understand which is this one:

```
2.Create a New File and set your syntax to "HTML (Dreamweaver)" for HTML or "JavaScript (Dreamweaver)" for JavaScript
```

**The issue is that i'm not getting the form, input, textarea, img, table colors changed.**

Comment: On the bottom right there should be the current syntax (HTML or JavaScript). If you click on that it should open a dropdown menu, where you can select *Dreamweaver > HTML (Dreamweaver)*. Or press ctrl+shift+p and write *Set Syntax: HTML (Dreamweaver)*.

Comment: oh thanx. please add as an answer. i will vote you